# Update a value based on criteria for each Unique Identifier

Tags: sql, database, oracle, case

I have a query where i would like to update a value based on a certain condition for each Primary key. For example, wherever TYPE is "ASBESTOS" and TYPE "CONTIN" is not present for this specific Project, id like to change the "ASBESTOS" to "CONTIN".

I've achieved this with the query below but this updates the whole populations ASBESTOS Values to CONTIN, even if CONTIN is already present, basically resulting in duplicate values. Should only add it if CONTIN is not already present. Perhaps a windows function will work so that it looks at each individual project, but i get a syntax error. Thank you for your help!

```
 SELECT PROJECT, 
 CASE WHEN TYPE = 'ASBESTOS' AND TYPE NOT IN 'CONTIN' THEN 'CONTIN' ELSE TYPE END AS TYPE, 
 SUM(OBLIGATION) AS OBS 
 FROM OBS_MASTER
 WHERE PROJECT = '074190'
 GROUP BY PROJECT, TYPE;

 Original:

 PROJECT      TYPE          OBS           
 074190      ASBESTOS     26326.99     
 074190        CM             0 

 Current Result:
 PROJECT      TYPE         OBS            
 074190        CM           0               
 074190      CONTIN      26326.99
```

Comment: Your query is not updating anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions to count the number of "CONTIN"s for each project, and then use that information for the aggregation key:

```
SELECT PROJECT, 
       (CASE WHEN NUM_CONTIN = 0 AND TYPE = 'ASBESTOS' THEN 'CONTIN' ELSE TYPE
        END) as TYPE
       SUM(OBLIGATION) AS OBS 
FROM (SELECT om.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'CONTIN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PROJECT) as NUM_CONTIN
      FROM OBS_MASTER om
     ) om
WHERE PROJECT = '074190'
GROUP BY PROJECT,
         (CASE WHEN NUM_CONTIN = 0 AND TYPE = 'ASBESTOS' THEN 'CONTIN' ELSE TYPE
          END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
SQL> with
  2  obs_master (project, type, obligation) as
  3    -- sample data
  4    (select 1, 'ASBESTOS', 2500 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 'CONTIN'  , 1500 from dual union all
  6     select 1, 'CM'      ,  500 from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 2, 'ASBESTOS', 1000 from dual union all
  9     select 2, 'CM'      , 1000 from dual
 10    ),
 11  temp as
 12    -- check whether project has CONTIN type
 13    (select project, min(type) cb_contin
 14     from obs_master
 15     group by project, type
 16     having type = 'CONTIN'
 17    )
 18  select a.project,
 19         -- if type = ASBESTOS and that project doesn't contain CONTIN,
 20         -- replace ASBESTOS with CONTIN
 21         case when a.type = 'ASBESTOS' and
 22                   b.cb_contin <> 'CONTIN'
 23              then 'CONTIN'
 24              else a.type
 25         end type,
 26         sum(a.obligation) obs
 27  from obs_master a left join temp b on a.project = b.project
 28  group by a.project,
 29         case when a.type = 'ASBESTOS' and
 30                   b.cb_contin <> 'CONTIN'
 31              then 'CONTIN'
 32              else a.type
 33         end
 34  order by a.project;

   PROJECT TYPE            OBS
---------- -------- ----------
         1 ASBESTOS       2500
         1 CM              500
         1 CONTIN         1500
         2 ASBESTOS       1000
         2 CM             1000

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to just update the type values, then something like the below statement might work:

```
UPDATE OBS_MASTER
SET TYPE='CONTIN'
WHERE TYPE='ASBESTOS' and 
  PROJECT not in 
  (select distinct PROJECT 
   from OBS_MASTER 
   where TYPE='CONTIN')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im not trying to update the table itself. Thanks for the help though